# How to use `document.getElementById("a_link").click();`

Tags: javascript

So, I need to use `document.getElementById("a_link").click();` in the website but I am not sure where or how to place it.

The setting that I have is that there is a `submit` button and `link` (http://demodemo.com)

I am trying to redirect users to the `link` when they press `submit` button.

I was told that `document.getElementById("a_link").click();` will do the job.

But I am not sure how to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why not an `onclick` handler on the button?

Comment: Yeah, I am realizing that maybe `onclick` will be better.

Comment: If it's a submit button, why not set the action attribute to the form tag? That's standard HTML, no JS required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your submit button and link look like this:

```
<button onclick="redirect()">Google.com</button>
<a href="http://google.com" id="a_link">Click the button instead fool</a>
```

Then, in your javascript, have this:

```
function redirect() {
    document.getElementById("a_link").click();
}
```

However, a much more eloquent way would be something like this:

```
<a href="http://google.com"><button>Click me for google.com</button></a>
```

This is simply a button inside of a link, making it so when you click the button, it will redirect you to google.com (or any other page of your choosing).

Comment: @steveKim if this helped you fix your problem, you can click the checkmark below the vote down button to accept the answer.